# Can navigator give you the language/languages in Angular Universal?

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

My question stems from the fact that navigator works for the browser but we don't have that on the server but in our codebase at work I have seen code like this:
`navigator.language.slice(0, 2);`

and of course we are using domino to provide these window objects

````
 win.Object = Object;
 win.Math = Math;
 global["window"] = win;
 global["document"] = win.document;
 global["branch"] = null;
 global["object"] = win.object;
 global["HTMLElement"] = win.HTMLElement;
 global["navigator"] = win.navigator;```
````

Answer (score 0):

No it cannot, `domino` provides a fake DOM server side.

You will need to either use a separate url for each language of your website, and/or save user preferences in cookies so that you can use the right language during SSR.